# With net-snmp 5.8, when using special characters (&,^,$) for encryption key and authentication key, a swnpwalk remote call fails

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I am running the following call from windows command line using snmpwalk.

```
snmpwalk -v 3 -a SHA -A 2OzqVwOQNZcImYBdI9Tfu9HcXFACVB7 
-x AES -X HfkFHRPpyDnGmdRSpI2X4b3ayGYVyeO -l authPriv 
-u sha_aes_DmSc7KCE2ggU 192.168.2.226 iso.3.6.1.2.1
```

Host 192.168.2.226 is a linux server. The user was created previously by running the following command in a ssh remote session:

```
sudo net-snmp-config --create-snmpv3-user -ro -a SHA 
-A 2OzqVwOQNZcImYBdI9Tfu9HcXFACVB7 -x AES 
-X HfkFHRPpyDnGmdRSpI2X4b3ayGYVyeO sha_aes_DmSc7KCE2ggU
```

The call worked fine in the previous case.

The problem came when the -A or -X parameter contained the special character ^. In any of those cases I got the following message:

```
snmpwalk: Authentication failure (incorrect password, community or key)
```

I tried escaping ^ character by using ^^ from windows command line, but It still failed.

Then I ran the snmpwalk call in the context of a ssh session (instead of calling remotelly from Windows console), and the call worked fine.

I would expect the call to work exactly in the same way. Anyone knows what I might be missing?

Answer (score 1):

The special symbol [^] needs to be enclosed in double-quotes for Windows, for example:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c 123abc"^"666 1.1.1.1
```